# Swagger does not reflect correctly POST endpoint definition in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I have a small endpoint

```
class SmallEndpointViewSet(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        //add the request.data data to the db

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
       // remove the data[pk] from db
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 url(
        r'^small-endpoint/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        mystuff_views.SmallEndpointViewSet.as_view(),
        name='small-endpoint'
    ),
    url(
        r'^small-endpoint/$',
        mystuff_views.SmallEndpointViewSet.as_view(),
        name='small-endpoint'
    ),
]
```

Everything works correctly except that in swagger, the post appears as

POST /small-endpoint/{id}

instead of

POST /small-endpoint/

A colleague told me that I need to send a paramater to as_view as this:

```
url(
            r'^small-endpoint/$',
            mystuff_views.SmallEndpointViewSet.as_view({
            'post': 'create'
        }),
            name='small-endpoint'
        ),
```

but then I receive the error TypeError: as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

I believe that APIView version of as_view doesn't receive parameters, and that is fine. What I really want is to swagger reflect correctly that the POST call does not need and id

How can I do that?